# Matrix multi upload - cells not appearing

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic

im running expression engine 2.7, matrix 2.5.6 with matrix multi upload 1.1.1

matrix fields can upload images no problem, but matrix multi upload doesnt create new cells once the images upload. I don't get any errors, the upload files show images are uploaded but the cells do not appear.

Please help, thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed Matrix MultiUpload is very fussy about paths and domains:

On a site (with identical build versions as yours) that is set up to be accessed via "www." and without prefix, or via an alternate domain alias, the control panel worked fine using either address, too – except for Matrix MultiUpload.

So, you might want to make sure that your site url configuration is identical to the hostname you entered in order to access the control panel.